# How to get a dict with example values without instantiating an instance of Pydantic model?

Tags: pydantic

With pydantic model as:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class CreatedScRequestResponseSchema(BaseModel):
    sc_request_id: int = Field(example=145781)
    sc_request_state_code: int = Field(example=200)
    sc_request_result_code: str = Field(example="positiv")
```

How could I get a dict with example values without instantiating an instance of the model:

```
{"sc_request_id": 145781, "sc_request_state_code": 200, "sc_request_result_code": positiv}
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could extract the examples from the `.model_fields` attribute, like so:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class CreatedScRequestResponseSchema(BaseModel):
    sc_request_id: int = Field(examples=145781)
    sc_request_state_code: int = Field(examples=200)
    sc_request_result_code: str = Field(examples="positiv")


def get_examples(model):
    examples_all = {}

    for name, field in model.model_fields.items():
        examples_all[name] = field.examples
       
    return examples_all

print(get_examples(CreatedScRequestResponseSchema))
```

Which prints:

```
{'sc_request_id': 145781, 'sc_request_state_code': 200, 'sc_request_result_code': 'positiv'}
```

Note that this does not handle recursion, so it only supports flat models.

UPDATE:
If you would like to support nested models you would need something along the lines of:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel, Field

class SubModel(BaseModel):
    id: int = Field(examples=1)
    name: str = Field(examples="John Doe")

class CreatedScRequestResponseSchema(BaseModel):
    sc_request_id: int = Field(examples=145781)
    sc_request_state_code: int = Field(examples=200)
    sc_request_result_code: str = Field(examples="positiv")
    sub_model: SubModel = SubModel(id=2, name="Jane Doe")


def get_examples(model):
    examples_all = {}

    for name, field in model.model_fields.items():
        if field.examples:
            examples = field.examples
        else:
            examples = get_examples(field.annotation)    
    
        examples_all[name] = examples
       
    return examples_all

print(get_examples(CreatedScRequestResponseSchema))
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Is it possible to handle nested models?

Comment: I added an example implementation for nested model